# Tab Activity not showing the fragment layout in application

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tabactivity

I have created a tabbed activity to show various information in. However, when creating a layout for the fragment, it does not show up on the application when being tested. The tabs are showing and it allows me to change tabs but the layout below is just a blank screen. I have tried to figure this out for a while now, can anyone help me with this? I will include all the relevant code below.

Java code for the first tab fragment:

```
package com.example.infocarmation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link CarDetailsReport#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class CarDetailsReport extends Fragment {

    TextView car, reg, colour, engineSize, fuelType, transmission, carType, 
    doors, seats;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public CarDetailsReport() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment CarDetailsReport.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static CarDetailsReport newInstance(String param1, String param2) 
    {
        CarDetailsReport fragment = new CarDetailsReport();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        car = car.findViewById(R.id.tvCarReport);
        reg = reg.findViewById(R.id.tvRegReport);
        colour = colour.findViewById(R.id.tvColourReport);
        engineSize = engineSize.findViewById(R.id.tvEngineSizeReport);
        fuelType = fuelType.findViewById(R.id.tvFuelTypeReport);
        transmission = fuelType.findViewById(R.id.tvTransmissionReport);
        carType = carType.findViewById(R.id.tvCarTypeReport);
        doors = doors.findViewById(R.id.tvDoorsReport);
        seats = seats.findViewById(R.id.tvSeatsReport);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
        getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CarDetailsPrefs", 
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String carStr = sharedPreferences.getString("Car", "");
        String regStr = sharedPreferences.getString("Registration", "");
        String colourStr = sharedPreferences.getString("Colour", "");
        String engineSizeStr = sharedPreferences.getString("Engine Size", 
        "");
        String fuelTypeStr = sharedPreferences.getString("Fuel Type", "");
        String transmissionStr = sharedPreferences.getString("Transmission", 
        "");
        String carTypeStr = sharedPreferences.getString("Car Type", "");
        String doorsStr = sharedPreferences.getString("Doors", "");
        String seatsStr = sharedPreferences.getString("Seats", "");

        car.setText(carStr);
        reg.setText(regStr);
        colour.setText(colourStr);
        engineSize.setText(engineSizeStr);
        fuelType.setText(fuelTypeStr);
        transmission.setText(transmissionStr);
        carType.setText(carTypeStr);
        doors.setText(doorsStr);
        seats.setText(seatsStr);


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_car_details_report, 
container, false);

    }
}
```

Code for the first fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CarDetailsReport">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="First Fragment" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tvCarReport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Car"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tvRegReport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCarReport" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tvColourReport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvRegReport" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the java code for the main activity:

```
package com.example.infocarmation;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class Report extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager2 pager2;
    FragmentAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        pager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager2);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        adapter = new FragmentAdapter(fm, getLifecycle());
        pager2.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Car Details"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Trip Monitor"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Logbook"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Other Details"));

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new 
        TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        pager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new 
        ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The java code for the fragment adapter:

```
package com.example.infocarmation;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    public FragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull 
    Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {

        switch(position) {
            case 1:
                return new TripMonitorReport();
            case 2:
                return new LogbookFragment();
            case 3:
                return new OtherDetailsFragment();
        }

        return new CarDetailsReport();

        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the code for the main activity xml which the tabbed fragments are linked to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Report">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It doesn't really matter about what is in the layout for now, or the java code for the fragment (strings, etc), just how to get the layout to show when in the application.

Comment: You're returning `0` for `getItemCount()` in your `FragmentAdapter`. That determines the number of pages to show.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what should I replace the 0 with to determine the number of pages shown? @MikeM.

Comment: I have no idea how many pages you want your app to have. You currently have four different `Fragment` classes being returned from `createFragment()`, so maybe you want four? I would also mention that in `createFragment()`, the `position` for the first page will be `0`, not `1`. Just FYI.

Comment: I've just tried it by returning 3, as you are correct, I want four different fragment classes. However, now it is causing the app to freeze and go back to the home screen. @MikeM.

Comment: Sounds like something's crashing. Have a look at your logs for a stack trace: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174. Also, if you want four pages, you need to `return 4;`. The `position` starts at zero, but total count works like normal.

Comment: I will have a look. Also I'm sorry, I just realised the wording in my question might have been wrongly understood. The tab layout is showing and working fine even when returning zero, it's just the layout of each tab is showing a blank white screen even though there is something there within the xml for each fragment. @MikeM.

Comment: You're fine. I knew what you meant. For future reference, in Android development world at least, tabs are only the little clickable buttons with the names. The bigger layouts that show when you click on tabs are usually called pages, no matter if you use `Fragment`s for them, or something else. Might help avoid some confusion.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thank you.